# White-space: nowrap did not work well, what did i do wrong?

Tags: mobile, browser, whitespace, nowrap

I make a responsive web page where at max width of 768px (via media query) the div inside the main container suppose to change to inline-block so that the page would scroll horizontally to the div's id when user click on link. The page is set up with overflow: hidden, so it navigate using id/anchor alone.

The problem is, when I did a preview in mobile, the container just spread out and I can totally swipe the page. Even the menu button that suppose to be in the center of the view port went to the center of the container. And leaving a huge white space below it. It did good however in desktop browser. So I presume it has everything to do with the nowrap function.

It worked in Firefox both mobile and desktop. It worked in I.E desktop. It did not worked in Chrome mobile but seems to be working in desktop. And failed in Safari mobile, haven't tested yet in desktop.

I tried to remove white-space: nowrap function only to find out the div did not stacks inline-block like it suppose to. I tried specified container's width and min-width with no luck. I tried float: left, position values and a bunch of things i don't recall them all. Nothing's change.

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="company" class="company">
    <iframe src="main.html">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content">
    <iframe src="content.html">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="system" class="system">
    <iframe src="system.html">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

## css

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  height: 100vh !important;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
}
#container .company, #container .content, #container .system {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh !important;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  #container {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #container .company, #container .content, #container .system {
  display: inline-block;
  }
}
iframe {
  width: 100vw !important;
  min-width: 100vw !important;
  height: 100vh !important;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
  border: none;
}
```

What I expected (Chrome desktop)
https://kamalmasrun.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/desktop.jpg

But only comes to this in mobile
https://kamalmasrun.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/screenshot_20190122-120510.png

Your help is much appreciated and I first address a thank you to all for the help =).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have a few problems here:

1. Setting `overflow: hidden` won't prevent browser on mobile from scrolling (on Firefox it might, but on Chrome or iOS Safari it will not). Blocking scrolling is a hard thing to do on mobile to be honest, and it always is a little bit hacky, so I would not go that way.
2. To achieve scrolling (or jumping) using links with `#content` etc, body has to be expanded and browser has to see where this element is. Expanding body will result in ability for user to scroll left/right, which is hard to block as I mentioned before. You have to scroll `#container` to show new element. You can do this using javascript.

Also, don't forget to add `overflow: hidden` to `#container` (this will work on mobile).

If something is still unclear, feel free to ask in comments below this answer :)

The idea of algorithm to achieve your goal:

1. Listen to `hashchange` event
2. Read current hash from `window.location`
3. Find element with given hash using `document.querySelector`
4. Read element's position inside container
5. Set `scrollLeft` property of container to be equal element's position

Some useful links to get you started:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

And updated CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#button {
  position: fixed;
  vertical-align: center;
}

#button .btn1,
.btn2,
.btn3 {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container .company,
.content,
.system {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  #container .company,
  .content,
  .system {
    display: block;
  }
}


iframe {
  border: none;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Hi Piotr, Thank you for the elaborate reply and sorry for the late reply, been struggling with my health issue lately. I've look into your suggestion, I might got some idea from that, if only i know how to execute it =D. I will, however, try my best to solve this. You are the best. Thank you again =).

Comment: Hi Piotr, sorry for the long gap reply, been struggling with those codes. I cannot do it myself (shame on me), so I've been searching up and down until I found this `if (window.location.href.indexOf(“#anchorname”) != -1) {window.onload = function (event) {window.location.hash = “#anchorname”;};}`. In which it jumps to the said anchor, no scrolling (I'm very desperate at this time), well, it worked! But it cancels my other java function on screen. I have to remove this & work on other function. I found that `overflow-x: auto` worked well too, but it doesn't seems to work with `scroll-snap-type`

Comment: Hey, could you show me your latest code? Maybe I could find a way to quickly improve it (i.e. add scroll instead of jump and some refactoring)

Comment: Hi Piotr, I was successfully use `scroll-snap-type` after putting much hours of r&d, it's not as great as auto scroll, but it'll do just fine for now. Few issues in Firefox mobile and maybe in Edge too, but I'll try to solve it, take it as a minor adjustment later on. But, I'll dive deeper into your suggestion however since my main plan is to auto slide to the content. For the java code i posted before, I didn't change anything in css, just plainly paste the code into my java snippet...

Comment: ...But here is the link to my web I did **[e-content](http://e-content.com.my/ver03)** if you please to see and grab some idea of what I'm facing in mobile. Well, I'm broken apart, to be honest~. The code mostly is in css style at **`@media screen and (max-width:768px)`** and that's that. Everything else outside the `<style>` is Muse's.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that setting min/max width to #container will do the trick.

```
#container {
    min-width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Also, I'd suggest using flex here, as it would suit well and is more modern.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work either. But I'll try flex like you suggested, I'll post an update later. Thank you very much for the help =).

Comment: Update: flex didn't work either. I tried my luck with clip: rect, same result (only weirder). The only thing that make menu went center to viewport and meta for disable pinch and zoom functioned was when i set overflow to hidden in the container. The downside is, anchors' not working. The page won't slide to next page. I am so lost and demotivated ='(.

Comment: Could you create some jsfiddle with this example? I'd then be able to try and solve it there

Comment: Hi Piotr, sorry for the late reply, been struggling with jsfiddle =D. Here is the best i can come up with, since I've been developing this web in muse, typing code is a nightmare for me. But, I'm pleased to learn something new. Here's the link [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nh1tzkc9/). It's however did not sliding to div id but jump instead and i can see flex: nowrap did not contain inline-block...well...inline when i shrunk the browser. I should make this more workable for you to look at but I don't know what I'm doing, I'm so sorry.

Comment: I've looked deeper into this problem. My answer now is too long to be posted here as a comment, so please check out my new answer.